# Expand granges object different amounts upstream vs. downstream

Tags: bioconductor, sequence-annotation, genomicranges

I am attempting to get gene regions and their immediate neighborhoods using Bioconductor GenomicRanges packages.

It is very easy for me to extend the regions around genes if I want to extend it the same distance upstream and downstream as in this example:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
library(Homo.sapiens)

genes = genes(Homo.sapiens)
genes_5kb_flank = genes + 5000
```

And if I want to extend both upstream and downstream different amounts centered on the TSS I can use `promoters(genes, upstream = 5000, downstream= 1000)`

But I am having trouble finding a function that is strand-aware and also chromosome length aware that allows me to extend the gene region a different amount upstream vs. downstream... For instance if I wanted a 5kb upstream flanking region and a 1kb downstream flanking region as is used for genomic region annotations on GREAT.

Anyone know of a drop in function for this?  something like `promoters()` but for the full gene region instead of only around the TSS?

Comment: Can't you subset on this data? I mean do upstream +5000 and downstream +5000 and then subset for those that are above 1kb downstream. Probably you can use `plyranges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a built in function for that, so here's a modified version of `promoters()`:

```r
expandRange = function(x, upstream=2000, downstream=1000) {
  strand_is_minus = strand(x) == "-"
  on_plus = which(!strand_is_minus)
  on_minus = which(strand_is_minus)
  start(x)[on_plus] = start(x)[on_plus] - upstream
  start(x)[on_minus] = start(x)[on_minus] - downstream
  end(x)[on_plus] = end(x)[on_plus] + downstream
  end(x)[on_minus] = end(x)[on_minus] + upstream
  x
}
```

You can then call `expandedGenes = expandRange(genes, 5000, 1000)`.

Comment: Thanks Devon this is a great.  The only problem I see with this function is that it doesn't take into account the length of the chromosomes when expanding the ranges -- when I tried to do something similar using `start()` and `end()` I kept getting errors that I expanded beyond the ranges of the chromosome.  This shouldn't be hard to fix though now that I have your function as a base, so thanks for your help!